# How to unhide rows that are not together succinctly?

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

I'm a beginner in coding and specially with VBA. I have an Excel document on which several rows are hidden. I need to unhide these rows, three or four at a time succinctly, until they are all unhidden. I have a button made out of a shape.

For now, my code ressemble this :

```
Sub UnhideObjectives()
Static currentStage As Integer

Rows("34:37").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("42:45").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Rows("50:53").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Select Case currentStage
Case 0
Rows("34:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
currentStage = 1
Case 1
Rows("34:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Rows("42:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
currentStage = 2
Case 2
Rows("34:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Rows("42:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Rows("50:53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
currentStage = 0

End Select
End Sub
```

But, I would like a code that does not have the `currentStage` function that get in cycle and optimally, it would need to show the rows that are next to the cell that got activated by the cursor.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand:

- You show the rows 34 - 37 always
- You hide rows 42 - 45 if stage is < 1
- You hide rows 50 - 53 if stage is < 2

  ```
  Rows("34:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
  Rows("42:45").EntireRow.Hidden = (currentStage < 1)
  Rows("50:53").EntireRow.Hidden = (currentStage < 2)
  ```

(note that you can omit the first line if there is no other instance that hides the rows 34 - 37)

After that, you jump to the next stage, but if the last stage (2) is reached, you jump back to the first stage (0). You can do this by adding 1 to the current stage and use the modulo operator:

```
  currentStage = (currentStage + 1) Mod 3
```

Advice: Always specify the worksheet you want to work with. So your code could look like:

```
Sub UnhideObjectives()
    Static currentStage As Integer
    With ActiveSheet ' (Or, for example, With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Rows("34:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Rows("42:45").EntireRow.Hidden = (currentStage < 1)
        .Rows("50:53").EntireRow.Hidden = (currentStage < 2)
    End With
    currentStage = (currentStage + 1) Mod 3
End Sub
```

**Update**: I don't understand what exactly you want to archive, but I guess you should have a look to the `Selection_Change` event. Maybe something like this (needs to be in the worksheet module, not in a regular module).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Offset(1, 0).Resize(3).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

`Target` is the selected cell.
`Offset(1, 0)` is the cell below
`Resize(3)` are the next 3 cells below
`EntireRow` means the complete 3 rows below the selected cell

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, I don't like currentStage. I would prefer if I could just put my cursor on a cell and then, the next hidden three rows would unhide.

Comment: Don't understand what you exactly want. Have a look to the update

Comment: Thank you, I already know this code, but it doesn't target specifically rows 34:37, 42:45, 50:53. I have more than just these rows that are hidden, but with this specific code, I would like to target these rows precisely.

Comment: Still not clear to me: You want to show row 34:37 when you click on a cell in row 33? With any condition? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Yes, exactly but specifically 34:37 even if 30:33 is hidden. My question is how to do it ? Because, specifically targeting these rows, so they can unhide when you click on a button and select a cell nearby, is too advanced for me.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused: When rows 30-33 are hidden, you obviously can't click on a cell in row 33 to show rows 34-37. Btw: buttons are easy to use, or, what I usually do is to use Shapes (you can assign a macro to them).

Comment: If you click on row 29 for exemple. I also use Shapes, my macro is named UnhideObjectives for now.

Comment: What if 23-28 is hidden as well as 30-33, what should row 29 make visible?

Comment: 30-33 would be optimal